# Slow initial webpack build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using React + Redux + Webpack but having an annoying development experience when every time I rerun the node server (using JetBrains WebStorm) it takes 2.5 minutes for webpack to bunde everything together.

I tried every possible technique to make webpack **initial** build faster but with no success. It takes 2.5 minutes to run this.

I tried:

- Babel caching
- Webpack module analyzer
- excluding node_modules

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```js
let path = require('path')
let webpack = require('webpack')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

let entry = {
    bundle: './src/index',
    vendor: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'redux',
        'react-redux',
        'react-router',
        'react-router-dom',
        'react-router-redux',
        'redux-thunk',
        'd3',
        'immutable',
        'moment',
        'axios',
        'openlayers',
        'react-table',
        'react-select',
        'reselect'
    ]
}

let plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js' }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV === 'prod' ? 'production' : 'development'),
            API_URL: JSON.stringify(API_URL),
            BASIC: JSON.stringify(BASIC)
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false,
        comments: false,
        compress: {
            sequences   : true,
            booleans    : true,
            loops       : true,
            unused      : true,
            warnings    : false,
            drop_console: true,
            unsafe      : true
        }
    })
]

const config = {
    entry: entry,
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory',
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
                },
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|less)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    `image-webpack-loader?${JSON.stringify(query)}`
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config
```

and here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "Aloha",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start-debug": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "webpack-stats": "webpack --profile",
    "startwatch": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "Aloha",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-react": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "eslint": "^4.12.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "d3": "^4.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "openlayers": "^4.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "rc-collapse": "^1.7.5",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-block-ui": "^1.1.1",
    "react-datetime": "^2.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-imageloader": "^2.1.0",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.15",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-table": "^6.7.4",
    "react-tabs": "^2.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "request": "^2.74.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```

Help will be deeply appreciated !

Comment: Why would you need to rerun the server ? Is your webpack dev server set up properly for hot reloading ?

Comment: Do you need to exclude node_modules from the other loaders (url/style/file)? It could be examining every node module directory for a css file or image file? HappyPack is a great tool that also saves on build time by parallelizing tasks

Comment: And what’s the contents of your babelrc file?

Comment: Sorry, and your postcss config JS file, if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

This is honestly not that surprising. It depends a lot on the complexity of your code and your machine. It takes about 1 min 15 seconds for my project on a high end iMac.

Personally if you’re new to development create-react-app is **still** a great starting point as it has hot reloading. Use webpack watch or something similar so you can see updates as you develop.

There should be no reason to rerun the node server after changes. The only time to rerun node will be when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire in webpack dev server, and I'm quite sure a solution can be found by using `concurrently`

In package.json, wire in `"dev":"concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""`

where `"server":"nodemon index.js"` and `"client":"webpack-dev-server ..."`.

I haven't tested this exact setup, but do use it with create react app where client is simply

```
npm run start --prefix client
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your machine. Make sure you have enough disk space and good processor for your project.
Apart from this, for more improvements you can go through this [link](http://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html).